# read-only svn access to hg repository

Tags: svn, mercurial

Hg is fine and all, however, there are some Svn-Features we (the development team) are really missing. Most importantly:

- being able to use "svn externals" to fetch (parts of) projects into subdirectories of other projects, and
- being able to only check out a subdirectory of a repository (mostly in combination with the first issue).

These are two rather pressing issues, while the benefits of Hg over Svn seem more and more to be nice-to-have features. This is, because I like tools to be fit for our (established and successful) workflow instead of changing our workflow to the paradigms of the tools.

So, one idea would be to maintain a read-only svn repository clone of our hg repository. After much googleing I found that bitbucket is actually trying something like this:

https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Using+Subversion+to+Access+a+Bitbucket+Repository

(and it seems, it does not work very well).

I am not interested in committing to the repository via svn nor do I need the full history available through svn. I just need the default tip available.

The most important repository is currently hosted on SourceForge. If this feature in BitBucket would have been working, I would not mind switching hosters. However, I do not want to maintain a server of my own (I got enough problems already).

Thus, my question is:

Does anyone know of a working solution to access a hosted Hg repository via Subversion?

The sad through is, if not, we might actually migrate back to svn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. AFAIK, no such (working) bridges exist - there are a lot of architectural differences in the core between hg and svn, which make "Mission impossible" (from my POV)
2. You can think about *hand-made bridge* for mirroring from Mercurial to Subversion (depending from your data mainly), which have to

   - `hg export` tip changeset (probably in hook) to patch-file (experiment with additional options, I have not idea, which can be useful)
   - `svn patch` your WC with the patch from the above point

From another side, I'll suggest read, study, check and evaluate [Subrepositories](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Subrepository) in Mercurial (but I'll recommend to use **from the beginning** [GuestRepo extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/GuestrepoExtension), which was created  in order to [avoid some shortcomings in Subrepos](https://bitbucket.org/selinc/guestrepo)).

This way you have not to change workflow, but have to only repositories structure under the hood: instead of using big monolithic repo for every project you use a set of smaller independent repos, which (thin) "superrepo" combines into project's repository (and subrepos will provide emulation /*to some degree*/ of sparse checkouts and externals from SVN-world)

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. I was hoping for such a hand-made bridge to already exist. Subrepositories (or GuestRepos) seem like a possibility, however, I am not sure if it is feasible to break up the existing repo now. Any experience with subrepositories?

Comment: @3of4 - "Any experience with subrepositories?" Well, in short - it works, but do not expect 100% similarity with the externals and external transparency: some commands require -s option explicitly for subrepo. And guestrepo is *slightly* closer to externals, than vanilla subrepo